# Como copiar um trecho de dados de uma string?

Tags: c#

Estou iniciando na área de programação e estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação de comunicação serial, onde, recebo strings de dados com algumas informações na qual preciso separá-las por categorias, por exemplo:

Uma string de conexão : `STX8abcdefETX<CRC>`

Uma string de Parâmetros: `STXNabcdefETX<CRC>`

onde, o *CRC* possui dois caracteres.

O que preciso fazer é monitorar a porta serial e quando chegar a string, identificar o inicio (*STX*), continuar lendo a mesma até encontrar o (*ETX*), contar mais dois caracteres e inserir em um *listbox*, o conteúdo lido.

As strings chegam todas juntas, por exemplo:

```
STX8abcdefETX<CRC>STXNabcdefETX<CRC>
```

Qual método utilizar ? Pois já utilizei `Substring`, `split`, mas como os tamanhos podem variar, as vezes pego o conteúdo errado.

Segue código alterado (RESOLVIDO).

```
    while (true)
        {
            posicaoSTX = bufferRx.IndexOf("STX");

            if (posicaoSTX != -1)
            {
                posicaoETX = bufferRx.IndexOf("ETX");
                if (posicaoETX != -1 && (bufferRx.Length >= (posicaoETX + 5)))
                {
                    posicaoETX += 3;
                    stringFinal = bufferRx.Substring(posicaoSTX, (posicaoETX - posicaoSTX) + 2);
                    bufferRx = bufferRx.Remove(0, posicaoETX);
                    trataProtocolo(stringFinal);
                }
                else break;
            }
            else break;
        }
```

Comment: você está recebendo esse STX como string, ou o char STX ? `char STX = '\u0002';` ??

Comment: Boa tarde Francisco. Recebo os dados da serial como string.

Comment: tens uma string de exemplo de um ciclo completo da comunicação ?

Comment: A melhor forma de fazer isso é com o `Regex.Split`, como sou um pouco leigo com regex, não vou arriscar fazer uma resposta por enquanto, mas fica a dica.

Comment: Então quer dizer que depois de toda a string tem 2 caracteres sobrando?

Comment: Sim, após todo ETX, tem dois caracteres, porém, eles fazem parte do protocolo e devem ser considerados.

Answer (score 0):

Com certeza há várias formas de fazer isso, tentei fazer um código didático pra você entender a lógica, espero poder ajudar:

```
        //Exemplo da mensagem recebida
        string mensagem = "STXMEnsagem1ETXSTXMEnsagem2ETXSTXMEnsagem3ETXSTXMEnsagem4ETXSTXMEnsagem5ETXSTXMEnsagem6ETX";
        //Lista para armazenar as mensagens
        List<string> mensagens = new List<string>();


        while (mensagem.Length > 0)
        {
            //Encontra o próximo STX
            int i1 = mensagem.IndexOf("STX");
            //Encontra o próximo ETX a partir do STX anterior
            int i2 = mensagem.IndexOf("ETX",i1);


            //Pega a SubString
            string sub = mensagem.Substring(i1+3,i2-3);
            //Retira a parte já processada da mensagem
            mensagem = mensagem.Remove(0, sub.Length+6);
            //Adiciona a mensagem à lista de mensagens
            mensagens.Add(sub);
        }

        //Quantidade de mensagens recebidas
        int count = mensagens.Count;

        //Imprime as mensagens na tela
        foreach (string s in mensagens)
            Console.WriteLine(s);
```

ps. Não fiz nenhum tratamento de erros.

Volto a comentar: acredito que o STX e ETX devam ser apenas um char, evitando assim os cálculos +3, -3, +6, etc.

Comment: Boa tarde a todos! Grato pelo apoio até o momento.O ideal seria uma solução parecida com a do Rovann, que lê o inicio e fim da string, porém, a string que será inserida em meu listbox, deverá conter o "STX" <os dados> e o "ETX" + <CRC> 2 caracteres.Ex de uma string recebida: STX80000000000ETX{-STX60000000000ETX´~, por exemplo, deverá ser inserida no listbox dessa maneira: (linha1) STX80000000000ETX{- e na (linha2) STX60000000000ETX´~. Porém, quando a string é muito grande, 310 caracteres, e vem junto a outras, por exemplo, dá erro de Startindex, Está fora da cadeia de caracteres.

Comment: @Lapnasc acredito que os erros de Startindex possam ser resolvidos apenas nos cálculos em `mensagem.Substring(i1+3,i2-3)` e `mensagem.Remove(0, sub.Length+6)`

Comment: Rovann, já dei uma ajustada nesses valores e a aplicação até funciona bem, consigo pegar as strings da forma que preciso. Dei uma debugada na rotina e percebi que dá o erro sempre que chega uma "sujeira" pela porta serial antes de uma string válida, exemplo: " \0 " antes da string e depois a string. Tem como ler a porta serial somente quando receber um STX, por exemplo?

Comment: esse `\0` é a terminação da string em C, você pode tratar com um if ou dar um replace removendo todos de uma vez: `mensagem = mensagem.Replace("\0","");`

Comment: Rovann, criei um formulário para testar as strings, e percebi que o erro ocorre sempre que, recebe uma string que não tenha nem o STX e o ETX, seja qual for o tamanho e quando não tem na string depois do ETX os dois caracteres que são referente ao CRC. Como mudei os cálculos das linhas que você mencionou, o erro ocorre com essas caracteristicas.

Comment: sim, como mencionei na resposta, não fiz nenhum tratamento de erros, no caso da string não ter os indicadores de início e fim, i1 e i2 darão sempre -1,  ocasionando os erros. O ideal é que se defina um protocolo para a comunicação, para assim poder aceitar ou recusar as mensagens recebidas e trata-las corretamente

Comment: Entendo. Tentei a solução indicada pelo Francisco, utilizando o Regex, porém, quando a string é adicionada no listbox, uma linha em branco é criada para cada string inserida.

Comment: aí fica fácil tratar o array, removendo as linhas em branco apenas

Comment: Após várias tentativas...rsrs...consegui ajustar o código para recebimento dos dados. Alterei o código que enviei anteriormente para o código que já está rodando e funcionando 100%...O mesmo também foi inserido aqui no forum para auxiliar os demais que também possam ter o mesmo problema...valeu pela força..

Comment: @Lapnasc que bom que resolveu, se alguma das respostas te ajudou, não se esqueça de marca-la como resposta e/ou avaliar. Abraços

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a melhor forma de fazer isso é com o `Regex`, veja como ficaria:

```
string[] arr = Regex.Split(valores, @"(?=STX)");
arr =  arr.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
listBox1.Items.AddRange(arr);
```

Não se esqueça de adicionar os namespaces no projeto:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/MyHZVN).

Veja também a documentação do [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) para entender melhor como funciona.

Comment: Bom dia Francisco. Testei sua opção, mas quando os dados são inseridos no listbox, criasse também uma linha em branco entre as strings. Tem como filtrar isso?

Comment: Sim, é facil fazer isso usando o LINQ, editei minha resposta, da uma olhada.

Answer (score 0):

Segue mais uma das formas de se fazer:

```
 public IEnumerable<string> ParseMessages( string messages )
 {
     //Separa o texto por STX....ETX
     var msgs = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches( messages, "STX.+?ETX" );

     foreach( var message in msgs ) 
         yield return message.Value;

     //Pega os dois ultimos digitos do crc
     yield return messages.Substring( messages.Length - 2 );
 }
```

Comment: Boa tarde a todos!

Comment: Boa tarde a todos! Grato pelo apoio até o momento.O ideal seria uma solução parecida com a do Rovann, que lê o inicio e fim da string, porém, a string que será inserida em meu listbox, deverá conter o "STX" <os dados> e o "ETX" + <CRC> 2 caracteres.Ex de uma string recebida: STX80000000000ETX{-STX60000000000ETX´~, por exemplo, deverá ser inserida no listbox dessa maneira: (linha1) STX80000000000ETX{-        e na (linha2) STX60000000000ETX´~. Porém, quando a string é muito grande, 310 caracteres, por exemplo, dá erro de Startindex, Parâmetro não pode ser negativo, etc..

Comment: @Lapnasc resposta editada.

Comment: Boa tarde Dunno, como sou novato nesse negócio de programação.rsr..como aplico sua rotina? Estou usando um form com um textbox para inserir as strings e um button que no evento click adiciona a string no listbox. Valeu.